# Datagridview with System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, timer

This problem caused the program to run a few minutes. Before I used `System.Timers.Timer` and not found problem ,until I changed to `System.Threading.Timer`.

I would like to know that ...

What is a root cause of this problem ?

How to solve this problem ?

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>InternetCafe.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>BindingSource cannot be its own data source. Do not set the DataSource and DataMember properties to values that refer back to BindingSource.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.get_Count()
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Count()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.Child_PropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at InternetCafe.Computer.NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\Computer.cs:line 163
       at InternetCafe.Computer.UsedTimeValueChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\Computer.cs:line 149
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.OnTimeChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 62
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.set_TimeSinceStartTime(TimeSpan value) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 30
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.tmrThreadingTimer_TimerCallback(Object state) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 50
       at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: BindingSource cannot be its own data source. Do not set the DataSource and DataMember properties to values that refer back to BindingSource.
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.get_Count()
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Count()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.Child_PropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at InternetCafe.Computer.NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\Computer.cs:line 163
       at InternetCafe.Computer.UsedTimeValueChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\Computer.cs:line 149
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.OnTimeChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 62
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.set_TimeSinceStartTime(TimeSpan value) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 30
       at InternetCafe.TimerManager.tmrThreadingTimer_TimerCallback(Object state) in C:\Users\at0m\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InternetCafe\InternetCafe\TimerManager.cs:line 50
       at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

---

**TimerManager Class**

Property TimeSinceStartTime

```
public TimeSpan TimeSinceStartTime
    {
        get { return new TimeSpan(timeSinceStartTime.Hours, timeSinceStartTime.Minutes, timeSinceStartTime.Seconds); }
        set
        {
            if (timeSinceStartTime != value)
            {
                timeSinceStartTime = value;
                OnTimeChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeSinceStartTime"));
            }
        }
    }
```

TimerManager Constructor

```
 public TimerManager(frmMainServer main)
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new
                   TimerCallback(tmrThreadingTimer_TimerCallback),
                   null, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 1000);
        _main = main;
    }
```

OnTimeChanged

```
private void OnTimeChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Timer callback

```
private void tmrThreadingTimer_TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        TimeSinceStartTime += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    }
```

---

**Computer Class**

Important Property

```
public decimal TotalMoney
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalMoney;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.totalMoney)
            {
                this.totalMoney = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalMoney");
            }
        }
    }

    public TimerManager UsedTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usedTimeValue;

        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.usedTimeValue)
            {
                this.usedTimeValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UsedTimeValue");
                usedTimeValue.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(UsedTimeValueChanged);       
            }
        }
    }
```

If time changed calculate fee, notify Usedtime and TotalMoney.

```
 private void UsedTimeValueChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       NotifyPropertyChanged("UsedTime");
       this.totalMoney = (decimal)(this.UsedTime.TimeSinceStartTime.Hours * this.session.Member.MemberTariff + this.UsedTime.TimeSinceStartTime.Minutes * (this.session.Member.MemberTariff / 60));
       NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalMoney");
   }
```

---

**Main Form**

Set CompList gridview datasource with dbBindingSource and set dbBindingSource datasource with Computers binding list.

```
public BindingList<Computer> computers = new BindingList<Computer>();
.
.
.
compList.DataSource = dbBindingSource;
dbBindingSource.DataSource = computers;
```

Comment: If it worked with the other timer, why did you change it?

Comment: Because when I used System.Timers.Timer and set like this "tmrTimersTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;" but it based on UI Thread. If UI thread it freeze, time will display incorrectly. So I would change to asynchronous timer.

Comment: If I answer incorrect, sorry for that I'm new. :)

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that you're changing a data source in a non-UI thread bound to a UI control.   The easiest solution is to use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) which will always execute on the UI thread, however, it's not very high resolution or accurate.  Your next option is to make sure your PropertyChanged are raised on the UI thread using a [SynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2007/09/05/synchronizationcallback.aspx) or by using [Invoke/BeginInvoke](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx).